# How to use a pdf document in an android app?

Tags: android

I want to read a PDF document through an android application developed my me. Then I want to sign it through an certificate recorded in the smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Here i post a project where you can easily generate pdf and read pdf. the project is in post it aims to provide a reusable pdf ganeration and pdf viewer code for Android. It was originally based on two open source projects.

Pdf writer code from: **[apwlibrary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/)**

Pdf reader code from: **[mupdf](http://code.google.com/p/mupdf-android/)**

Activity ScreenShot
**[img1](http://rehman-furniture.com/attaullahcs/stackdir/s1.gif)** & **[img2](http://rehman-furniture.com/attaullahcs/stackdir/s2.png)**

**[Here Source Code](https://codeload.github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer/zip/master)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if you have an idea how to sign the PDF ,don't hesitate because i need this information very much .